# EXCEL: Returning MAX Value where the number has appeared more than once

Tags: excel, function, max

I am looking to return a MAX value from a large amount of data where the the value has appeared more than once.
There are over 1500 rows and I'm trying to work out the MAX value for each row (working across horizonatally). However, I'm struggling to work out how to do this...searching the forum, I can see mentions of DMAX but I'm not sure this would work.

I have attached screenshots of the data to show what I mean...

Thanks,
James

[image: MAX Value Screenshot]

Comment: Can you clarify what result you want - do you want a single result from all 1500 rows, giving you the largest value that occurs more than once in any single row.......or do you want a value for each row, i.e. the largest value in each row that occurs more than once in that row?

Comment: Hi Barry - Each row is a particular item - across the row is a week ending date and total sold for each week for that item. At the end of the row, I've attemtped to calculate the MAX sold for all weeks - However, the required MAX value that I want is a value that appears more than once. For example, going across, if I had 10, 7, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5 - I would want 7 because that is the MAX value that has appeared more than once. Hope this makes more sense than my previous attempt at the problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this "array formula" in row 6

`=MAX(IF(COUNTIF(E6:EX6,E6:EX6)>1,E6:EX6))`

Needs to be confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` so that curly braces like { and } appear around the formula in the formula bar

Now copy formula down the column. If there are no repeated values in a row the result will be zero